# Dropdown menu that behaves like the native menu bars

Tags: jquery

I know there's hundreds of jQuery plug-ins for dropdowns, but I can't seem to find the one that fits my needs. Requirements as follows:

1. Dropdowns open on click
2. If a dropdown is open, the rest of the dropdowns open on hover
3. Dropdowns close only until you click.

This is very similar to how MacOS manages its menu bar, I think Windows does the same.

The menu in [Google's Code Editor](https://docs.google.com/macros/) behaves pretty much like this, for reference.

I can't have jQuery UI as an additional dependency. My application is already fat as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of using a big plugin, you could always make your own suited to your specs, it's pretty trivial with minimal code:

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mh3Pm/

HTML:

```
<ul id="main_nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#main_nav > li {
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
}

ul.sub_nav {
    display: none;
}

#main_nav.active ul.sub_nav.active {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('ul#main_nav').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul#main_nav').length == 0) {
        $('ul#main_nav').removeClass('active');
    }
});

$('ul#main_nav > li > a').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('ul.sub_nav').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('ul.sub_nav').addClass('active');
});
```

I'm sure it's not perfect, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: This is just perfect, I tried my own but it was buggy and full of exceptions, so I threw it away. Thank you so much!